# Multicast traffic to Kubernetes

Tags: docker, networking, kubernetes, multicast

I want my pods to receive multicast network traffic flowing from outside of my kubernetes cluster to specific ports in my nodes.

I'm considering two solutions:

1. Adding `hostNetwork: true` flag to their `yaml` file along with `hostPort` configuration in order to receive the traffic directly to the pod.
2. Forwarding the traffic locally on the nodes from `eth0` interface to `docker0` interface using `iptables` command.

Method 1 is an official feature in Kubernetes, but it feels like breaking a security wall that docker originally imposed, and might cause port 
collisions with host's processes, etc.

Method 2 on the other hand transparently forwards the multicast network traffic to the pods.
Despite the fact I can use an automation tool to spread this configuration (ansible/salt etc), anything configured 'out of the scope' of Kubernetes feels a little hacky to me.

Would like to hear your pros and cons, comments, and maybe other solutions to the problem of multicasting to a kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we picked method 1, as it is the documented way to achieve what we wanted, and I can report that it works fine.

Comment: Is your cluster running on on-prem? It seems this solutions would not work on Cloud given that they do not support multicast, e.g. [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-faq#do-vnets-support-multicast-or-broadcast)

Answer (score 6):

A cleaner way to support multicast is to add an additional interface to your PODs through `multus-cni`. Then, you could associate this new `multus` interface to your host network interface that will receive multicast traffic on the host. Summarizing, you will have two interface on your POD i.e:

1. `net1` (default) for pod-to-pod communication and other unicast traffic.
2. `eth0` (multus) for multicast traffic. Then you will need to "join" it with a NIC in your host machine, either by using `bridge` or `macvlan`

See more details here: https://github.com/intel/multus-cni/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md

Comment: For those on the 'edge', microk8s has a [multus addon](https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-multus) which saved me lots of time routing local UDP traffic into a pod on my cluster

Answer (score 1):

I heard that WeaveWorks supports multicast: https://www.weave.works/use-cases/multicast-networking/

[github issue](https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/issues/3737) has few words on multicast support

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have much more info myself, as I was also researching this. Feel free to add to this in your own answer if you do find more info.

Comment: Please read [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). If you think your answer does not have the quality that is expected, then avoid posting it. The other way is posting as a comment, but since you dont have enough reputation, you cannot do so.

Comment: I would indeed have posted this as a comment if I could have

Comment: Thanks @RikSchaaf