# multicast udp packets to all kubernetes pods on different nodes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, spring-integration, google-kubernetes-engine

I'am searching on how to send multicast udp packet to pods in my kubernetes cluster

after some investigation in this issue  i realized that  all my pods can see packet only if it running on the same node other pods that living on another node can't see the routed packet,

i have test it on my [gcp](https://cloud.google.com/) account , i haven't test it on any other k8s cloud providers
i have implement it using java spring boot integration see my [git repo](https://github.com/ashraf-revo/megana)

i have implemented two modules

```
    <modules>
        <module>livefeed</module> #read packet on the network on 4444 port
        <module>livesender</module> # multicast 1 packet every 1 second
    </modules>
```

i have made my deployment kind `DaemonSet` to make sure kubernetes schedule every pod on different node

i am using spring integration to read routed packet as 
    `@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow processUniCastUdpMessage() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(new MulticastReceivingChannelAdapter("224.0.0.1", 4444))
                .handle(x -> log.info(new String(((byte[]) x.getPayload()))))
                .get();
    }`

I hope someone can help me if should i configure vpn on gcp or something else.

Answer (score 1):

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48304357/multicast-traffic-to-kubernetes), you need to configure your kubernetes cluster to add the following config for multicasting to function correctly:

```
hostNetwork: true
dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have tried it didn't work till now, did you tried it on gcp

Comment: i found that google vpc say ` VPC networks only support IPv4 unicast traffic. They do not support broadcast, multicast ` see  https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc   does it mean this is my problem

Comment: Yes, in GCP this restriction which will stop you from using multicast am afraid. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: does aws allow you

Comment: In theory you can do this using transit gateway with weave net but i don't haven't tried it myself so can't say for sure. see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/how-multicast-works.html.